# Can float be round tripped via double without losing precision?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, precision, floating-point-conversion

If I have a C# `float`, can I convert it to `double` without losing any precision?

If that `double` were converted back to `float`, would it have exactly the same value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. IEEE754 floating point (which is what C# must use) guarantees this:

1. Converting a `float` to a `double` preserves *exactly* the same value
2. Converting that `double` back to a `float` recovers *exactly* that original `float`.

The set of `double`s is a superset of `float`s.

Note that this *also* applies to `NaN`, `+Infinity`, and `-Infinity`. The signedness of zero is also preserved.

Answer (score 7):

Let's test this with code:

```
[Fact]
public void IsFloatRoundTrippableToDouble()
{
    var bits = default(FloatUnion);
    bits.FloatData = float.MinValue;

    var testBits = default(FloatUnion);

    // ReSharper disable once LoopVariableIsNeverChangedInsideLoop
    while (bits.FloatData <= float.MaxValue)
    {
        var d = (double)bits.FloatData;
        testBits.FloatData = (float)d;

        if (bits.IntData != testBits.IntData)
            Assert.True(false);

        bits.IntData -= 1;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
private struct FloatUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public uint IntData;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public float FloatData;
}
```

This code tests every `float` value between `MinValue` and `MaxValue` (except `NaN`, infinities, etc...). The in-memory byte representation is compared to ensure no other conversions take place.

Though it might seem crazy to test the ~4 billion possible floating point numbers, it actually runs in around 11 seconds on my machine.

And yes, the conversion is safe. Converting from float, to double, then back again doesn't lose any information.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you posted this, would it not be more fitting in documentation?

Comment: I disagree. It's still a good question, and answer. There is no harm in answering your own question.